# How to get fully qualified url with selenium on a link without any href attribute?

Tags: selenium

I would like to retrieve url from a  link on an html page. 
unfortunately, html code does not contain any href attribute (I suppose it is managed by some javascript code)

Here is html code  :

```
<p class="ng-scope">
  <a class="documentLink ng-binding" data-document-id="21928499">Electronic document</a>
</p>
```

I tried to do it with `getattribute()` function :

```
By linkPodPopover = new ByXpath("//div[@class='popover-content']//a[contains(.,'Electronic document')]");
find(linkPodPopover).getAttribute("href");
```

but it returns an empty String...

I also tried with this code but also without success :

```
driver.getCurrentUrl()
click(linkPodPopover)
```

Do you see another way ?

Comment: What is the rendered html in the browser at the time the test is run?

Comment: Sounds like the location is not changing, so you'd need the URL the script sends to and get/post the data the script sends.

Comment: @Greg ,html is well rendered. In fact, the only problem is due to link which does not have any href attribute in html code, but i suppose that this href should be generated in some javascript code.

Comment: finally, I came accross this problem by using browserstack functionnalities : https://www.browserstack.com/automate/java#enhancements-uploads-downloads.  It allows to click on the download link, then the browser download it. then using javascript, I can check if file is well donwloaded, and if size and md5 are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any answer on the internet.

And I tried to explore every javascript attribute of the DOM element of my link without finding URL.

Finally, I came across this problem by using browserstack functionnalities : http://browserstack.com/automate/java#enhancements-uploads-downloads
It allows to click on the download link, then the browser download it. then using Javascript, I can check if file is well downloaded, and if size and md5 are correct. –